# mysql monitoring and management

Tags: java

i want to monitor and manage mysql database sever with jmx. when i hit google it display connector/mxj. i get it and execute MysqldHtmlAdaptor file. it shows mysql server variables. but i can't rivet that instance into original mysql server running on other server.

plz help.

is there any good tutorial for JMX for mysql ...

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL server does not support JMX natively, so you'll need to write something yourself that acts as a bridge between JMX and the MySQL management tools; [MySQL Server Status Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/server-status-variables.html) is probably a good place to start.